# Maven 2 and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, maven-2

I have been trying to figure this out all day.  I've searched SO and Google extensively but I can't seem to find something for very basic beginners.  Basically Im an intern where I am required to setup Maven and then setup Hibernate.  I have maven setup and is running as it should.  But when it comes to Hibernate I am just drawing blanks on what to do.  The documentation isn't the best and the only tutorials I find are if you want to setup Hibernate with an IDE.
[This is the tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#tutorial-firstapp-setup) I am following and it starts off assuming you have already setup the Hibernate environment with almost no explanation as to how to actually set it up.

My questions are

- How do I setup Hibernate
- How do I use integrate Hibernate into Maven.  I try to follow the tutorial but I have 
  errors saying missing dependencies.  I included the jars in my CLASSPAST environment var and I still get the errors.  I understand the dependencies are referenced in the POM but I don't get why mine messing up.

Also I read that I need to create a Maven project that is setup for Hibernate but that never helps.  I try to use what I think is the appropriate archetype:

```
 mvn archetype:generate 
     -DgroupId=org.hibernate.tutorials 
     -DartifactId=hibernate-tutorial 
     -DarchetypeArtifactId=jpa-maven-archetype 
     -DarchetypeGroupId=com.rfc.maven.archetypes
```

Although none of the folders referenced in the tutorial are generated and I get the default App.java file which I don't know if that matters if I delete that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate is not very Maven friendly. They are using another build tool internally - that's why I guess.

To setup a Hibernate Maven-based application please just follow [their tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/tutorial.html) that you mentioned and not use any archetypes. It will give you a real Hibernate application integrated with Maven.

Oh, and I see where your confusion is coming from. The tutorial doesn't *start off assuming you have already setup the Hibernate environment*! The only thing you need to create are the directories listed there in bold - `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources` and `src/main/webapp`. Together with a `pom.xml` they will become the *Hibernate environment* - all Hibernate JAR will get downloaded automatically and your project will get built once you run something like `mvn package` ;-)

And of course Hibernate tutorial has a **BUG** in it (for a couple of years it seems) described in [this forum post](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=998479). So please use the last (at the bottom) pom.xml from the link. It uses version `3.6.1`, but  since today the latest is `4.0.0` but I wouldn't dare to use it ;-) You may want to use the latest 3.x.x though which is `3.6.9` - just replace version numbers in `pom.xml`

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I tried to basically do exactly what the tutorial says and I get these errors http://i.imgur.com/rNRxC.jpg. So I dont even need to download the Hibernate distribution? It does all of that for me via Maven?

Comment: exactly - Maven will download it for you and store it in local repository (so that it doesn't need to download it each time build is executed). the error you get is missing version numbers - let me look into the this for a sec...

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps a ton!  I have a side question also.  My task this week is to setup a Maven 2 environment and implement a design pattern for ex. lets say strategy pattern.  I did that already.  Then I was told to setup a JBoss AS, then the last task is to take the Unit Of Work pattern and setup a version in which I use Hibernate for it. Then within a unit test persist the object ie a person w/ a first and last name.  Implement that by using JPA annotation.  I guess my confusion on the last part is what does it mean to 'persist' the object. I appreciate all of your help so far!

Comment: Persist means create/update a record in the database. So you've got a Person (Java object) filled with data (first/last name), and you need to store it into database table (probably `person`) using Hibernate -- I'm sure you will succeed in that :)

Comment: Ah ok that makes it much clearer! You've been extremely helpful.  Thank you very much